# Is custom Theme applicable to Salesforce Mobile App?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, mobile, theme-branding

We have feature to set the custom theme using Themes and Branding(SETUP > THEMES AND BRANDING) for lightning desktop apps, but looks like system wont carry same settings to Salesforce mobile app by default.

As I checked "Salesforce Branding" under Setup > Apps > Mobile Apps > Salesforce > Salesforce Branding, it allows use to set Brand color but wont change the complete theme such as button's color, path colors etc.

So am i missing something to enable the theme for Mobile Salesforce App?

Thanks,
Shrivaths

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, button color is only customizable when Consumer Goods Cloud is enabled: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.se_task_edit_col_button_macros.htm&type=5

Which is misleading as the help documentation for OOB App branding includes messaging about buttons, but have had the same experience that you refer to.